# Ragdoll 2D Aiming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bulletphysics

So I need help with starting something. I have a `ragdoll` for a `2D` platformer that I've got moving and he's able to stand on his feet.

So now I have made a gun as a child of his forearm, and I want to have the character aim with his gun wielding hand using mouse input (`x`, `y` movement of the mouse). Where the player aims and shoots, that's where the projectile will travel. I currently don't know how to start with that.

My character movement mainly runs through physics, and I want it like that cause I want the recoil of my weapon to add force to the character so he can fly.

I haven't really done much besides, creating the empty `GameObject` for where my projectiles will spawn. Also I have created a script to read player input, then instantiate projectiles.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so you want to:

1. Rotate the weapon in the mouse direction
2. Shoot the bullets from the weapon
3. Add a recoil force from the shot

There're indeed many methods to implement this, so let me show you how I'd do it my way. I assume you haven't done it yet, so I'll try to explain as clear as I can.

---

## 1. Create a player

I assume you have already implemented this logic, so that's how my player looks like

[image: Player hierarchy]

- `Player` has a `Rigidbody2D`
- `Body`, `Arm` and `Weapon` all have a `BoxCollider2D`
- `Handle` is an `empty GameObject`, which has a `Weapon` inside of it. Changing the `Handle`'s `Z` rotation, rotates the `Weapon` as you want

[image: Player's handle]

---

## 2. Rotate the weapon in the mouse direction

[image: Rotate the weapon in the mouse direction]

The `α` (alpha) represents the `Z` rotation of our `handle` in `degrees`, that's the value we need to get.

First, we get the `mouse position` and convert it from `screen` to `world` space.

```cs
Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
Vector2 worldMousePos = _mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenMousePos); // from screen to world space
```

`_mainCamera` will be our `Camera.main`, assigned in the `Start` method.

```cs
private void Start()
{
    _mainCamera = Camera.main;
}
```

To ensure we don't have issues with performance, we store the previous mouse position as `_prevMousePos` and check if our current isn't the same. This way we don't make any useless calculations, which affect the performance.

```cs
Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

if (mousePos != _prevMousePos)
{
    // any further calculations are performed here

    _prevMousePos = mousePos;
}
```

As I drew on the image above, we first have to calculate the `offset` between the `mouse` and `handle` positions. This gives us the `x` and `y` sides of the imaginary triangle.

```cs
Vector2 offset = worldMousePos - (Vector2)transform.position;
```

Now, according to the [tangent ratio](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=919db838b2730857&q=tangent+ratio&source=lnms&uds=AMwkrPuGmGHzVOyOb5Id-xnvNDHTy3n3x5T-GCNPwfF-Y7VZoiqzD79MLC6-o7--582te2pqIH5K4gLFcsqjZEAmgtucpG-gSTjF7ChbVcxsqDpZJgFhb929So1H_wyQjfq2axX7bxCRee8JvuDe7r9_A-7e8zTpFcDBeXAvJOvVMSjeu0jvAZdQ2tGcrU3dwuvOeYoER3jm2yoe1n_SrfDRk2T7V639_CVw-j5FHmrgAKJrIrburlCxdEmsa72C62E1Ig7hxL8RVmJXBvvd9i702QMHMvnWElIyKkOc9N97-o64WO6oRvc&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUtZOS_J6FAxUIQ_EDHWpuAHsQ0pQJegQIEhAB&biw=1536&bih=730&dpr=1.25), our formula looks like this, where `x` is `offset.x` and `y` is `offset.y`.

[image: tangent formula]

`tan^{-1}` is called `arc-tangent`, and there are 2 similar methods to do this. The explanations are taken from this methods' summaries.

```cs
Mathf.Atan(offset.y / offset.x); // Returns the arc-tangent of f - the angle in radians whose tangent is f
Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x); // Returns the angle in radians whose Tan is y/x
```

I'd suggest using `Atan2`. It returns an angle in `radians`, so we have to convert it to `degrees`, as this is what Unity's rotation eulers use. We can use `Mathf.Rad2Deg` (Unity's radians-to-degrees conversion constant).

```cs
Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```

Now, we can create a method which returns the distance angle in `degrees`.

```cs
private float GetDistanceAngle(Transform transform, Vector2 screenMousePos)
{
    Vector2 worldMousePos = _mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenMousePos);
    Vector2 offset = worldMousePos - (Vector2)transform.position;

    return Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}
```

We rotate the `weapon` just around the `Z` axis, so we have to assign just it. This isn't possible setting `transform.rotation.z` directly, unless you know how to translate it (which you don't really need to know).

We use `Quaternion.Euler` method with `Vector3.forward` multiplied by the angle, which is the same as `new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle)`, but more readable, as for me. Let's create a method out of it.

```cs
private void RotateTransform(Transform transform, float angle) =>
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle);
```

We can clamp the `angle` we get between the `mininum` and `maximum` values serialized in the `Inspector` as `weaponRotMin` and `weaponRotMax`.

```cs
public float weaponRotMin = -90f;
public float weaponRotMax = 90f;
```

```cs
float angle = Mathf.Clamp(GetDistanceAngle(weaponHandle, mousePos), weaponRotMin, weaponRotMax);
```

And so our current logic, which rotates the `weapon` in the direction of the `mouse`, looks like this.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

    if (mousePos != _prevMousePos)
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Clamp(GetDistanceAngle(weaponHandle, mousePos), weaponRotMin, weaponRotMax);

        RotateTransform(weaponHandle, angle);

        _prevMousePos = mousePos;
    }
}

private void RotateTransform(Transform transform, float angle) =>
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle);

private float GetDistanceAngle(Transform transform, Vector2 screenMousePos)
{
    Vector2 worldMousePos = _mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenMousePos);
    Vector2 offset = worldMousePos - (Vector2)transform.position;

    return Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}
```

---

## 3. Shoot the bullets from the weapon

### 3.1 Instantiate a bullet

[image: Shoot the bullets from the weapon]

We have to shoot, which means spawning the bullet, when the player presses the `left mouse button`.

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    // ...
```

This can be also implemented with other keys like `Space`, for instance.

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    // ...
```

We have to serialize the `bullet` and `bullet holder`, where the `bullets` are spawned, in the `Inspector`.

```cs
[Header("Bullet")]
[SerializeField] private Transform bullet;
[SerializeField] private Transform bulletHolder;
```

We spawn the `bullet` prefab using `Instantiate` method, the 2nd parameter is the `parent` the `bullet` is spawned in.

```cs
Transform newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, bulletHolder);
```

Then we have to get an `offset`, as shown on the image above.

We get the `angle`, which is the `Z` position of the `bullet` and translate it from `degrees` to `radians`, as we'll have to pass it into `sin` and `cos`.

Note that the it's not `rotation.z`, for the reason I've mentioned above, in the 1st header.

```cs
float angle = weaponHandle.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
```

The `diagonal`, named `PC` on the image, is the half of the `weapon` and `bullet` `lossyScales`, which, unlike the `localScale`, is in `global` coordinates.

```cs
float diagonal = (weapon.lossyScale.x + bullet.lossyScale.x) * .5f;
```

Now, according to the [`cosine`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cosine+ratio&sca_esv=62807fa8b11614b1&biw=1536&bih=730&ei=RrgJZpCuKKWCxc8PxoaZoAk&ved=0ahUKEwiQ6dCAnZ-FAxUlQfEDHUZDBpQQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=cosine+ratio&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiDGNvc2luZSByYXRpbzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzINEAAYgAQYigUYQxiwAzINEAAYgAQYigUYQxiwA0jxIFD8BFj0HnADeAGQAQCYAZIBoAH7BqoBAzMuNbgBA8gBAPgBAZgCB6AC6wPCAgYQABgHGB7CAgsQABiABBiKBRiRAsICChAAGIAEGIoFGEOYAwCIBgGQBgqSBwM0LjOgB4Iq&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) and [`sine ratio`](https://www.google.com/search?q=sine+ratio&sca_esv=62807fa8b11614b1&biw=1536&bih=730&ei=S7gJZrSuM4DBxc8P8qK5uAM&ved=0ahUKEwj0_4yDnZ-FAxWAYPEDHXJRDjcQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=sine+ratio&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiCnNpbmUgcmF0aW8yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yChAAGIAEGIoFGEMyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgARI6EhQpkNYi0hwA3gBkAEAmAFuoAHHA6oBAzQuMbgBA8gBAPgBAZgCBqAChwLCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgINEAAYgAQYigUYQxiwA5gDAIgGAZAGCpIHATagB4Ab&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), out formulas look like this.

[image: cosine formula]

[image: sine formula]

And as we multiply them both by the `diagonal`, our `offset` is gotten this way.

```cs
Vector2 offset = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * diagonal
```

In order to get position of the instantiated `bullet`, we have to add the `offset` to the `position` of the `weapon`, as shown on the image.

Let us create a method for the `offset`.

```cs
private Vector2 GetBulletOffset(Transform bullet, float direction)
{
    float angle = direction * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    float diagonal = (weapon.lossyScale.x + bullet.lossyScale.x) * .5f;

    return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * diagonal;
}
```

And now assign the new `position` of the `bullet` to the `weapon`'s `position` added to the method's result.

```cs
Vector2 offset = GetBulletOffset(newBullet, direction);

newBullet.position = (Vector2)weapon.position + offset;
```

Now, in order to make a `bullet` that's not a perfect circle be shot correctly, we have to rotate it as shown on the image.

The `rotation` is the same as that of the `weapon`, and we can use previously created `RotateTransform` method.

```cs
RotateTransform(newBullet, weaponHandle.eulerAngles.z);
```

Let's create a full method of out it, which takes the `rotation` of the `weapon` as the parameter.

```cs
private void Shoot(float direction)
{
    Transform newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, bulletHolder);

    Vector2 offset = GetBulletOffset(newBullet, direction);

    newBullet.position = (Vector2)weapon.position + offset;
    RotateTransform(newBullet, direction);
}
```

And now the full `bullet spawn` logic looks like this.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        Shoot(weaponHandle.eulerAngles.z);
}

private void Shoot(float direction)
{
    Transform newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, bulletHolder);

    Vector2 offset = GetBulletOffset(newBullet, direction);

    newBullet.position = (Vector2)weapon.position + offset;
    RotateTransform(newBullet, direction);

    AddRecoilForce(offset);
}

private Vector2 GetBulletOffset(Transform bullet, float direction)
{
    float angle = direction * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    float diagonal = (weapon.lossyScale.x + bullet.lossyScale.x) * .5f;

    return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * diagonal;
}
```

### 3.2 Make the bullet fly

I assume, you already have a `bullet` `GameObject` and there's nothing hard in its creation. Just make sure not to assign a `Rigidbody2D` with the gravity enabled.

We have to create a script for the `bullet`, which can be called `BulletController`.

Let's assign its `speed` in the `Inspector`.

```cs
public float speed = 10f;
```

Now, there are lots of ways to make it fly, so let's just use `transform.Translate` method in `Update`.

The `bullet` will fly e.g. to the right, which we multiply with the `speed` and `Time.deltaTime`, to make the bullet fly with the same `speed`, regardless of the `frames per second`.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector2.right);
}
```

It doesn't really matter, but we can add a `lifetime` field to destroy the `bullet` after the certain amount of seconds, but I am sure you can implement the desired logic yourself.

With the added `BulletController` script, the `bullet` flies as soon as it is spawned in the `PlayerController` script. So an example of the `bullet` script might look like this.

```cs
public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float lifetime = 3f;

    private void Start() => StartCoroutine(Destroy());

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector2.right);
    }

    private IEnumerator Destroy()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(lifetime);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

## 4. Add a recoil force from the shot

[image: Add a recoil force from the shot]

The `recoil force` usually happens in the opposite direction of the shot.

The `force` is usually applied with `Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2 force)` method, so we have to assign the `Rigidbody2D` in the `Start` method first.

```cs
private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
```

```cs
private void Start()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

- If we have an `angle` of `45` `degrees`, both `x` and `y` sides of the `triangle` are `equal`, which should give us a `Vector` of `(.5, .5)`. This way, the `force` applied to the `x` and `y` axes is **the same**.
- If we have an `angle` of `90` `degrees`, which `triangle` is basically a **straight line** (although it's not even a triangle), the `Vector` of `(0, 1)` is returned, giving us the `force` fully on the `y` axis, which makes the `player` jump upward (downward, in our case, as the direction is opposite)

Now, I have great news for you. We have already calculated the `direction` of the `force` with this line in the `Shoot` method.

```cs
Vector2 offset = GetBulletOffset(newBullet, direction);
```

Although there's a problem: the `offset` may be both:

- `(10, 20)`, with a ratio of `10 / 20 = .5`
- `(100, 200)`, with a ratio of `100 / 200 = .5`

And even though the `ratios` are the same, the applied `force` will be 10 times greater in the second variant.

That's why we use `Vector2.normalized`, which returns the `Vector` with the same `ratio`, but the maximum value of `1` (meaning 100%).

So in both variants the same `Vector` of `(.5, 1)` is returned. This allows us to apply the same force to the player, regardless of the `offset`.

Let's serialize the `recoilForce` field in the `Inspector`, for us to easily adjust it.

```cs
public float recoilForce = 10f;
```

And create an `AddRecoilForce` method, which adds the `normalized force` multipled by `recoilForce` and `10`, to not make `recoilForce` too big.

```cs
private void AddRecoilForce(Vector2 direction) =>
    _rigidbody.AddForce(10f * recoilForce * -direction.normalized);
```

The method should be called directly in `Shoot` method with the previously assigned `offset` parameter, so it'll look like this.

```cs
private void Shoot(float direction)
{
    Transform newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, bulletHolder);

    Vector2 offset = GetBulletOffset(newBullet, direction);

    newBullet.position = (Vector2)weapon.position + offset;
    RotateTransform(newBullet, direction);

    AddRecoilForce(offset);
}

private void AddRecoilForce(Vector2 direction) =>
    _rigidbody.AddForce(10f * recoilForce * -direction.normalized);
```

---

## Full code

Now, the full code, with some `regions` for readability, looks like this.

The `PlayerController` is assigned to the `Player`, and `BulletController` to the `Bullet` prefab.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Fields

    [Header("Values")]
    public float recoilForce = 10f;

    public float weaponRotMin = -90f;
    public float weaponRotMax = 90f;


    [Header("Body")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform weaponHandle;
    [SerializeField] private Transform weapon;

    private Camera _mainCamera;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    private Vector2 _prevMousePos;


    [Header("Bullet")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform bullet;
    [SerializeField] private Transform bulletHolder;

    #endregion

    private void Start()
    {
        _mainCamera = Camera.main;
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        #region Aim

        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

        if (mousePos != _prevMousePos)
        {
            float angle = Mathf.Clamp(GetDistanceAngle(weaponHandle, mousePos), weaponRotMin, weaponRotMax);

            RotateTransform(weaponHandle, angle);

            _prevMousePos = mousePos;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Shoot

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Shoot(weaponHandle.eulerAngles.z);

        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotates the transform around its Z axis
    /// </summary>
    private void RotateTransform(Transform transform, float angle) =>
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle);

    /// <returns>
    /// The angle between the transform and mouse positions
    /// </returns>
    private float GetDistanceAngle(Transform transform, Vector2 screenMousePos)
    {
        Vector2 worldMousePos = _mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenMousePos);
        Vector2 offset = worldMousePos - (Vector2)transform.position;

        return Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Spawns a bullet and applies the recoil force to the player
    /// </summary>
    private void Shoot(float direction)
    {
        Transform newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, bulletHolder);

        Vector2 offset = GetBulletOffset(newBullet, direction);

        newBullet.position = (Vector2)weapon.position + offset;
        RotateTransform(newBullet, direction);

        AddRecoilForce(offset);
    }

    /// <returns>
    /// The offset between the weapon and bullet positions
    /// </returns>
    private Vector2 GetBulletOffset(Transform bullet, float direction)
    {
        float angle = direction * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        float diagonal = (weapon.lossyScale.x + bullet.lossyScale.x) * .5f;

        return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * diagonal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a recoil force in the opposite direction
    /// </summary>
    private void AddRecoilForce(Vector2 direction) =>
        _rigidbody.AddForce(10f * recoilForce * -direction.normalized);
}
```

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float lifetime = 3f;

    private void Start() => StartCoroutine(Destroy());

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector2.right);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Destroys the bullet after lifetime seconds
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerator Destroy()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(lifetime);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```